# Unrecognized option: -home Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: command-line, java

My Ubuntu was OK. After trying to install Hadoop, I get this error. Why?

```
java -home

Unrecognized option: -home Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

java version is OK:

```
java -version

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

`-home` is not a standard `java` option. Was there a tutorial that said to use it? To find the Java home directory (if it is set) you would do

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Should you be setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable instead (with the underscore not the dash)? For example adding a line to `hadoop-env.sh` to tell it the Java home directory:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/[your-jdk-directory]
```